# jQuery livequery - cleanup function firing when it should not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, livequery

I have the following code, which is supposed to set the **main_table_on_page** variable according to the actual table presence in the document...

```
$('table#main_middle_table').livequery(function() {
    if ($("table#main_middle_table").attr("id")) {
        window.main_table_on_page = true;
    } else {
        window.main_table_on_page = false
    }
}, function() {
    window.main_table_on_page = false;
});
```

... however, the cleanup function (the second one) fires directly after the first function, resulting in **main_table_on_page** being always set to **false**. These functions are fired when I change the content of my main content DIV element (via AJAX), which might or might not contain the table.

Any ideas? :)